# Weird current at 8051 port 1 pin

Tags: 8051

The pins in Port 1 has internal pull-ups when used for input.
The Mosfet is off and the drain is pulled high using an internal pull-up resister.

[image]

I connect an ammeter and see that the current (IL current) flowing to ground is about 15uA. I inferred that the value of the internal pull-up resister is 333k.

Now I connect a 10k resister and measure the current. I get 0.5mA (5/10k). What happened to the internal pull-up resister? Is not the internal pull-up resister and the 10k resister in series?

[image]

What is happening? 
When I use external pull-up at Port 0, things appear as expected - Resisters in series and both resisters acting as voltage divider to create a voltage drop at the pin.

ps: I am using [AT89s52](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1919.pdf).

ps: The same problem exists in port 2,3

ps: Here is the current for different resisters:

```
- 330 ohms - 15uA
- 1k - 15uA
- 100k - 50uA 
- 220k - 22uA
```

The Max IL (as per datasheet) is -50uA

Comment: What happens if you change the 10k resistor for 4k7 or 2k2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an informed guess rather than a definite answer, but I suspect there isn't a resistor there at all: resistors take up a lot of area in CMOS and aren't very accurate. Instead there will be a small current source made out of MOSFETs and limited to 50uA. It might be non-linear to guarantee that, no matter what pulldown you connect, the input is close to one rail or the other.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are right. Either that, or something supernatural. What is amazing is that datasheet does not say more than, it to be a pullup resistor.